# opencart store installation issue

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce, opencart

I have installed my store to live and getting this **error**.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: boss_megamenu in /home/develop1/public_html/domain/catalog/view/theme/bt_gomarket/template/common/header.tpl on line 109

Notice: Undefined variable: header_top in /home/develop1/public_html/domain/catalog/view/theme/bt_gomarket/template/common/header.tpl on line 110

Notice: Undefined variable: header_bottom in /home/develop1/public_html/domain/catalog/view/theme/bt_gomarket/template/common/header.tpl on line 111
```

Please send me the best solution

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you have not set `this variables in your connroller header.php`. maybe you make some mistakes, but in local your machine the displaying of errors is turned off.

Look into you controller and try to fund this variables: `boss_megamenu`, `header_top`.

Comment: yes, you are right. can you please tell me how can i fund this variables or from where i can get it ?

Comment: this variable should be created in your controller, but you said that there are no such variables. I don't know what you want to set into this variable(boss_megamenu, header_top, header_bottom ). That's why one of the way is delete them from header.tpl. Or another way is to set this variables in your controller header.php.